# ZeroMQ crashed when created workers with std::thread

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am porting the [lbbroker.c example](https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/lbbroker.c)  from the ZeroMQ Guide Book to the higher level API `czmq`.

For some reason, a `std::thread` that creates and connects to an endpoint using a `zsock` always crashed. 
Here is the code for load-balancing broker written using C++:

```
//  Load-balancing broker
//  Demonstrates use of the CZMQ API

#include <czmq.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define NBR_CLIENTS 10
#define NBR_WORKERS 3
#define WORKER_READY   "READY"      //  Signals worker is ready

//  Basic request-reply client using REQ socket
//
void client_task()
{
    std::cout << "Start client...\n";
    zsock_t *client = zsock_new_req("tcp://*:5672");
    // zsock_t *client = zsock_new_req("ipc://frontend.ipc");
    std::cout << "Client connect...\n";
    // zsock_connect(client, "ipc://frontend.ipc");

    //  Send request, get reply
    std::cout << "Client send HELLO\n";
    zstr_send(client, "HELLO");
    char *reply = zstr_recv(client);
    if (reply) {
        printf("Client: %s\n", reply);
        free(reply);
    }
}

//  Worker using REQ socket to do load-balancing
//
void worker_task()
{
    std::cout << "Start work task...\n";
    zsock_t *worker = zsock_new(ZMQ_REQ);
#if (defined (WIN32))
    // worker = zsock_new_req("tcp://localhost:5673"); // backend
#else
    // worker = zsock_new_req("ipc://backend.ipc");
#endif
    std::cout << "Worker connect\n";
    zsock_connect(worker, "tcp::/localhost:5673");
    // zsock_connect(worker, "ipc://backend.ipc");
    //  Tell broker we're ready for work
    zframe_t *frame = zframe_new(WORKER_READY, strlen(WORKER_READY));
    zframe_send(&frame, worker, 0);

    //  Process messages as they arrive
    while (true) {
        zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv(worker);
        if (!msg)
            break;              //  Interrupted
        zframe_print(zmsg_last(msg), "Worker: ");
        zframe_reset(zmsg_last(msg), "OK", 2);
        zmsg_send(&msg, worker);
    }
}

//  .split main task
//  Now we come to the main task. This has the identical functionality to
//  the previous {{lbbroker}} broker example, but uses CZMQ to start child 
//  threads, to hold the list of workers, and to read and send messages:

int main(void)
{
    zsock_t *frontend = zsock_new_router("tcp://*:5672");
    zsock_t *backend = zsock_new_router ("tcp://*:5673");
    // zsock_t *frontend = zsock_new_router("ipc://frontend.ipc");
    // zsock_t *backend = zsock_new_router ("ipc://backend.ipc");

    // printf("Create server threads");
    for (int worker_nbr = 0; worker_nbr < NBR_WORKERS; worker_nbr++) {
        std::thread t(worker_task);
        std::cout << "Created worker...\n";
    //     pthread_t worker;
    //     pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_task, (void *)(intptr_t)worker_nbr);
    }
    int client_nbr;

    std::cout << "Create client threads\n";
    for (client_nbr = 0; client_nbr < NBR_CLIENTS; client_nbr++) {
        std::thread t(client_task);
    //     pthread_t client;
    //     printf("Create client thread %d", client_nbr);
    //     pthread_create(&client, NULL, client_task, (void *)(intptr_t)client_nbr);
    }

    //  Queue of available workers
    zlist_t *workers = zlist_new();

    //  .split main load-balancer loop
    //  Here is the main loop for the load balancer. It works the same way
    //  as the previous example, but is a lot shorter because CZMQ gives
    //  us an API that does more with fewer calls:
    while (true) {
        zmq_pollitem_t items[] = {
                                  { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
                                  { frontend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
        };
        std::cout << "Running\n";
        //  Poll frontend only if we have available workers
        int rc = zmq_poll(items, zlist_size(workers) ? 2 : 1, -1);
        if (rc == -1)
            break;              //  Interrupted

        //  Handle worker activity on backend
        if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            //  Use worker identity for load-balancing
            zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv(backend);
            if (!msg)
                break;          //  Interrupted

#if 0
            // zmsg_unwrap is DEPRECATED as over-engineered, poor style
            zframe_t *identity = zmsg_unwrap(msg);
#else
            zframe_t *identity = zmsg_pop(msg);
            zframe_t *delimiter = zmsg_pop(msg);
            zframe_destroy(&delimiter); 
#endif

            zlist_append(workers, identity);

            //  Forward message to client if it's not a READY
            zframe_t *frame = zmsg_first(msg);
            if (memcmp(zframe_data(frame), WORKER_READY, strlen(WORKER_READY)) == 0) {
                zmsg_destroy(&msg);
            } else {
                zmsg_send(&msg, frontend);
                if (--client_nbr == 0)
                    break; // Exit after N messages
            }
        }
        if (items[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            //  Get client request, route to first available worker
            zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv(frontend);
            if (msg) {
#if 0
                // zmsg_wrap is DEPRECATED as unsafe
                zmsg_wrap(msg, (zframe_t *)zlist_pop(workers));
#else
                zmsg_pushmem(msg, NULL, 0); // delimiter
                zmsg_push(msg, (zframe_t *)zlist_pop(workers));
#endif

                zmsg_send(&msg, backend);
            }
        }
    }
    //  When we're done, clean up properly
    while (zlist_size(workers)) {
        zframe_t *frame = (zframe_t *)zlist_pop(workers);
        zframe_destroy(&frame);
    }
    zlist_destroy(&workers);
    zsock_destroy(&frontend);
    zsock_destroy(&backend);
    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it with `g++ lbbroker.cpp -o lbbroker -lzmq -lpthread`. It compiled successfully, however, when running, I got an exception and a core dumped:

```
Created worker...
terminate called without an active exception
Start work task...
aborted (core dumped)
```

It crashed in the `worker_task` function. According to GDB, it seems 1 thread successfully created and then the program crashed. The C version works fine.

Comment: You have to `join` or `detach` your thread before a scope the thread is created ends. You can add `vector<thread>` in main, add move all created `std::thread t(worker_task);` into this vector. Then join all threads at the end of `main`.

Comment: The main function got an infinite loop down there, so is `join()` necessary?

Answer (score 0):

C++ has destructors which are called at the end of the scope where the variable was declared.

In the case of `std::thread`, if the destructor is called with a joinable thread, `std::terminate` will be called. You are supposed to decide whether you want to `join` the thread or `detach` it before you arrive to the destructor.

So either you detach the threads (and therefore they will run free without an easy way to wait for them to finish), or you increase the lifetime of the objects and join them later on.